# Does UWP app support to show its fullscreen on Lock Screen?

Tags: uwp

I know that some Windows 10 app can show a gadget control on Windows 10 lock screen. E.g. Spotify

https://superuser.com/questions/1454049/disable-media-controls-on-the-windows-10-lock-screen

But my UWP app shows fullscreen as its normal mode, and I want to show it on lock screen with fullscreen mode as well. Is it possible?

Comment: That's a system media control, not a Spotify gadget. You can add information to the system media control by using the [SystemMediaTransportControls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.SystemMediaTransportControls) class. [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/integrate-with-systemmediatransportcontrols) has more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only badge that UWP can display on the lock screen interface.

Currently UWP does not provide related APIs to enable applications to display on the lock screen.